# Only build Angular 9 project once for package output and running tests

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

In our CI we currently run `ng test` before `ng build`. Since the upgrade to Angular this leads to the full project being compiled twice. Once for the tests and once for the build.

This is taking up about 2 minutes of extra time in our CI, but it is a redundant tasks.

Is it possible to run the jasmine tests against the compiled output?

Comment: I don't think it's possible but, to me it makes sense build once.  Reason: ng test does all the build stuff, you'd have to dig into the internals to bypass the build and point to the right directory during CI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution to this trivially simple. Just change the order of `ng build` and `ng test`, so that the build happens first. Test will then be executed on the compiled output.

This is even better, as it confirms that the test run against the exact code you are about to publish.